# Facebook Graph api users search

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search

I'm using Facebook graph Api to search users and data that i get is kinda different from that i get from Facebook UI. For example search response of User interface is friends, mutual friends and other related data in first. How can i query to get related data for current user ( i.e friends and mutual friends in first place).

Here is query that i'm using to search users.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/search?fields=id,name,picture.type(normal)&limit=50&q={q}&type=user&access_token={token}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and data that i get is kinda different from that i get from Facebook UI

That’s because those are two completely different things.

The search functionality offered via the UI is called Graph Search. But the powerful possibilities that offers are not exposed via API. (To protect user privacy, and keep apps from doing extended user profiling via that data.)

Searching via API is limited to what is listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search

That’s not much – but it’s all you get.