# Facebook Graph API - smart search

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm searching users with Facebook Graph API at the endpoint "/search" with "type=user", but the results do not return in the same order as if I searched through Facebook (which is a lot smarter).

How can I achieve the same result?
i.e., the people I'm most likely searching for should be ordered first, just like the Facebook website.

Comment: API search results should already be tailored to the specific user to some extent, if you use a user access token for the request. Apart from that, there’s nothing else you can do. The API search functionality is very rudimentary.

Comment: That's exactly what I'd want, but it's not happening. Logging in my app with the same user (me) and calling the API, gives me different results than when I'm in Facebook's website.

Comment: That is a different issue – see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36524170/1427878

Comment: My point is, it's not just different, it's completely stupid, there is no prediction what so ever, I searched for my name and there were 20 (+ paging) "Rodrigo Ruiz"... but not me! And I was logged as myself...

Comment: Perhaps they excluded that deliberately, because people should hardly ever have a need to _search for themselves_? (Schizos & brain-damaged individuals excluded, of course :P ) Most users might think, “Hey, I am obviously trying to find _other_ people that have the same name as me, why did they include me in those results? _That’s_ completely stupid.”

Comment: I tried doing search logged in with a test user in my app and added me as his friend, I still don't show up.

Comment: My advice: Don’t bother. As I said already, API search can be considered rudimentary at best. And btw., what would even be the use case of letting people search other users via your app?

Comment: To invite someone for instance.

Comment: That’s what [App Invites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites) and the [`invitable_friends` endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/invitable_friends) are for. (Yes, that is limited to friends of the user – but imagine the amount of spam it would create, if people could invite just anyone … you’d most likely get _flooded_ with invites from shady app developers trying to promote their own sh*t.)

Comment: I cut off the details, but imagine a messaging application, I want to send a message to someone, so I search all Facebook user, if the user already has the app, I show a "send" button, else I show a "invite" button.

Comment: _“but imagine a messaging application”_ – part of Platform Policy is that you are not supposed to replicate Facebook “core functionality” – and with chat on facebook.com and the Facebook Messenger app, that might be a no-go to begin with …

Comment: -.-... there is more to it than that, I'm just giving you enough to explain the question.

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API is not a copy of the Facebook UI. Many functions differ and others are not even available via the API.

There is no option or way to get the exact same search results via the API.

Comment: But is there a way to get better predictions than just giving the results in order? I mean, to make the API consider the user that is logged.

Comment: The search endpoint doesn't work with a app token and requires user or page token. Results for both are the same. So the answer is: No.

Comment: Is there a practical way for using the Facebook Graph Search API in an application? The way I was able to use it is unpractical for anyone, since it's just a search in all users (a lot of them with the same name).

Comment: Your question was about "how can I..." not about if the only way it works is practical or not.